# cumulative count of character vector

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to make a cumulative count of country names from a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(country = c("Sweden", "Germany", "Sweden", "Sweden", "Germany",
                             "Vietnam"), year= c(1834, 1846, 1847, 1852, 1860, 1865))
```

I have tried different version of count(), cumsum() and tally() but can’t seem to get it right.

Output should look like:

```
country year n
Sweden  1834 1
Germany 1846 2
Sweden  1847 2
Sweden  1852 2
Germany 1860 2
Vietnam 1865 3
```

Comment: I think you are looking for cumulative sum on the duplicated elements `cumsum(!duplicated(df$country))#[1] 1 2 2 2 2 3`

Comment: Thank you @akrun! Problem solved,

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>% mutate(count = cumsum(!duplicated(.$country))) %>% as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   country  year count
#>    <fctr> <dbl> <int>
#> 1  Sweden  1834     1
#> 2 Germany  1846     2
#> 3  Sweden  1847     2
#> 4  Sweden  1852     2
#> 5 Germany  1860     2
#> 6 Vietnam  1865     3
```

or
    dist_cum <- function(var)
      sapply(seq_along(var), function(x) length(unique(head(var, x))))

```
df %>% mutate(var2=dist_cum(country))
#>   country year var2
#> 1  Sweden 1834    1
#> 2 Germany 1846    2
#> 3  Sweden 1847    2
#> 4  Sweden 1852    2
#> 5 Germany 1860    2
#> 6 Vietnam 1865    3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
df<-data.frame(country=c("Sweden","Germany","Sweden","Sweden","Germany","Vietnam", "Germany"),year= c(1834,1846,1847,1852,1860,1865,1860))
counts <- ddply(df, .(df$country, df$year), nrow)
```

The output is:

```
> counts
     df$country df$year V1
1    Germany    1846  1
2    Germany    1860  2
3     Sweden    1834  1
4     Sweden    1847  1
5     Sweden    1852  1
6    Vietnam    1865  1
```